# Why does java give a int too large error despite the type of the variable being declared as a double?

Tags: java

Java gives me ***integer number too  large*** error message for the corresponding line of my code which I will signify with ***** in the corresponding segment of my code:

```
...

if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
    double number = input.nextDouble();
    if (number >= 10000000000) //***** {
        System.out.print("The number is greater than 10 billion!");
    }
}

...
```

I thought that the double type can record about 15 decimal digits. Can you please tell me what is going on?

Comment: Your number IS an integer. You can mark numbres as Double with suffixing the number with a D or a Long with suffixing it with an L. Like 100D or 1L.

Comment: Indeed, the *variable* is a `double`, but the literal you are using (`10000000000`) is an `int`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java is complaining about the actual number in your source code, i.e. the integer *literal*, not the storage location you chose for it (which would entail an automatic conversion). Since the language says that any unsuffixed number is interpreted as an `int`, you need to add a suffix for the type you want that literal to have, such as `d` for `double`:

```
 number >= 10000000000D
```

Comment: Note that either `D` or `d` works as suffix. I think `d` is the most widely used variant.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed values must be defined based on their source code representations, i.e. literals. Even you define a variable as double, the value which you assigned it will be seen as integer, If you don't indicate its type.

Let me give some example:

1. 10000000000---> integer literal
   10000000000D---> double Literal
   2.long socialSecurityNumber = 999999999L;--->long literal
2. float pi =  3.14_15F;---> float literal

For more information you can check the following link:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be

Because `10000000000` is `int` and it can not be  stored because it is more than `2,147,483,647`, that is why you are getting the error **integer number too large**

to fix the issue,  make it `Double` by appending `d`

```
if (number >= 10000000000d) //***** {
    System.out.print("The number is greater than 10 billion!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact you are comparing the int with a double doesn't change what is an acceptable int value.

If you make the number a double, it might be clearer.

```
if (number > 1e10) {
    System.out.print("The number is greater than 10 billion!");
```

BTW I would use `>` if the message is "greater than" otherwise I would have

```
if (number >= 1e10) {
    System.out.print("The number is greater than, or equal to 10 billion!");
```